# ISTQB Software Testing Foundation course

Tags: manual-testing, learning, istqb

I'm very much interested in taking ISTQB Software Testing Foundation course.

But before I start with the course I wish to familiarize myself with Software Quality Assurance & Testing.

So are there any online sites that might help me with the syllabus also with mock exams?

Please send links !!!

Comment: You can check this blog for suggestions and recommendation for ISTQB Foundation exam :http://testingcycles.com/index.php/2018/06/19/istqb-certification/

Answer (score 5):

The official site for downloading syllabus and materials:
http://www.istqb.org/downloads/syllabi/foundation-level-syllabus.html
http://www.istqb.org/downloads.html

Additional links to go thro:

https://www.testingexcellence.com/istqb-quiz/istqb-foundation-practice-exam-1/
http://istqb.patshala.com/

Comment: thanks a lot Bhavani i went through the notes site and mock exam site very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](https://testanart.wordpress.com/) provides a helpful Q&A cheat sheet for the ISTQB exam. Unfortunately, it doesn't cover all of the syllabus (only The Fundamentals of Testing, Life Cycles, Static Testing and Test Design Techniques).

[This one](https://www.rogeriodasilva.com/istqb-theory-summary/) has a more complete list and a printable cheat-sheet.

Plus, there are some more example tests [at softwaretestinghelp.com](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/).