# Software Testing certification

Tags: learning, certification

I'm a `software engineer` over 5 year experience in J2EE, but on a break from last 4 years.

Now I want to start career in `software testing` so,  can anyone please help me which certification should I go for.

I googled and there are a lot of courses available so I'm very confused where to start from.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of courses and certifications for testing, but everyone tends to start at Foundation Level and then works towards a certain specialism from there.

The overview of available courses (below) was taken from [istqb.org](https://www.istqb.org/) (who you can find out more about [here](https://www.istqb.org/about-as.html)).

[image: ISTQB roadmap]

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide some good reference websites (or book) if want to prepare for foundation level.

Comment: Hi @Jeena, there are loads of resources available - most of which have already been listed on SQA: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29913/istqb-software-testing-foundation-course, https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5227/where-can-i-find-istqb-foundation-mock-exams-with-reliable-answers, https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9313/career-change-in-to-testing, https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/what-options-are-available-in-the-career-path-of-a-tester

Comment: @Jeena, you're welcome. Please feel free to upvote and accept my answer if it's been useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another training for testers is *Black Box Software Testing* (**BBST®**)

Course description here: https://www.associationforsoftwaretesting.org/training-2/
Some of materials you will find here: http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST/

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to get into the aws ecosystem where there is a great deal of opportunity for automation and testing.

So consider going for their architect / appdev / devops certifications and then use book, videos, etc. (there are many available, see amazon, etc) to guide your learning path.  Once you have all this knowledge on-board you will have learned that there are many opportunities for adding value and improving quality by using automation within the AWS ecosystem such as:

### CloudFormation

Infrastructure as Code is the Holy Grail of modern development. Aws have a detailed offering with Cloudformation to create controlled, replicable infrastructure. You create templates in YAML/JSON and use them as the method to provision the resources for a given implementation (stack). You can eliminate instance drift with immutable deployments.

### Device Farm

The aws Mobile device farm allow you to test both native and mobile web applications on A wide number of Android and Apple devices. You can test both manually and through automation.

### CloudWatch

Automatic Notification of when things are a bit out of whack. Costs, machines, usage, many metrics
Pretty much any services which describes 'automatically doing x' is an opportunity for an automation engineer, because, at some point, a person needs to write that automation or the parameters to use.
At least for a little longer.